# How do i downsample an 8 bit bitmap array of size 20x30 to 10x15

Tags: c#, image-processing

How do i downsample an 8 bit bitmap array of size 20x30 to 10x15

`original_bitmap_array[20][30]` to `downsample_array[10][15]`

this is the original array which is `1` and `0` representation of character 'A'

```
00000000111100000000
00000001111100000000
00000001111100000000
00000001111110000000
00000011100110000000
00000011000110000000
00000011000111000000
00000011000011000000
00000111000011000000
00000110000011000000
00000110000011000000
00000110000011000000
00001110000001100000
00001110000001100000
00001100000001100000
00001100000000110000
00001100000000110000
00011111111111110000
00011111111111111000
00011111111111111000
00011111111111111000
00111111111111111000
00110000000000011000
00110000000000011100
01110000000000011100
01110000000000001100
01110000000000001110
01100000000000001110
11100000000000000110
11100000000000000111
```

Now can somebody tell how to downsample into 10x15 array, without losing the char 'A'?

Comment: If i had any clue of this, i definitely would have tried. It just i don't known anything about down sampling. Isn't this the reason why this website is for? If you don't have anything productive to say please abstain from asking " Have you tried ? ", it will save both our time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you want to sample the image.
One easy sampling for your example is to take every second pixel from the 20x30 and put in 10x15.

You probably want to expand this and sample at the cross-section of 2x2 pixels and use bi-linear interpolation.

Because i don't exactly now how you want to sample the image it is hard for me to give you more information on this.

Update:

```
org_img[20][30]; --monochrome values
sampled_img[10][15];

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        int average = org_img[2*i][2*j] + org_img[2*i+1][2*j]+ org_img[2*i][2*j+1] + org_img[2*i+1][2*j+1];
        average = average>>2; --integer division by 4.
        sampled_img[i][j] = average;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a monochrome 8 bit bitmap, which i have converted to 1 and 0 array. I want to reduce the size of the array because training neural network with array of size 20x30 takes long time. I thought i could reduce this training time if reduce the array to a more practical size of 10x15. I want to do this by retaining significant quality of the original array. Now you understand what trying to say?

Comment: take a look at my edit. I have not tried the code but it should work. Don't convert the monochrome to 0 and 1. You will not save any space because there is no "bit" type in c# smallest type is byte.

Comment: Hmmm can you plese tell me where? max value of i=9 and j=14. Edge indexing is at org_img[i*2+1][j*2+1] which is org_img[19][29] and this is fine.

Comment: thanks brano i think this should work, give me sometime and i will  try it and let you know.

Comment: Please take a look at it again, i have edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Matrix.Scale` function for this.

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33h63fz9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: that's a cool function, but the document doesn't say anything about how the down sampling is done.  kinda curious how....